# How can I add a number to all the words with a specifc string in bash?

Tags: bash

I have a file (not tab-delimited)

```
chr22   bed2gff .   16850754    16850929     1000   .   .   .;
chr22   bed2gff .   17556275    17556923     864    .   .   .;
chr22   bed2gff .   17558078    17558342     642    .   .   .;
chr22   bed2gff .   17558390    17558813     941    .   .   .;
chr22   bed2gff .   17558918    17559181     698    .   .   .;
chr22   bed2gff .   17565343    17566824     542    .   .   .;
chr22   bed2gff .   17565448    17565617     603    .   .   .;
```

I want the file to be in a way like this:

```
chr22   bed2gff1    .   16850754    16850929     1000   .   .   .;
chr22   bed2gff2    .   17556275    17556923     864    .   .   .;
chr22   bed2gff3    .   17558078    17558342     642    .   .   .;
chr22   bed2gff4    .   17558390    17558813     941    .   .   .;
chr22   bed2gff5    .   17558918    17559181     698    .   .   .;
chr22   bed2gff6    .   17565343    17566824     542    .   .   .;
chr22   bed2gff7    .   17565448    17565617     603    .   .   .;
```

So that the "bed2gff" is unique in every row

I'm still a beginner in bash and I'm facing a lot of problems using awk and sed , is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v postvar=1  '{$2=$2 postvar; postvar++}1' input
```

Here, `postvar` is a variable which is initially assigned the value of 1. Inside `awk` execution block , the second column is merged with `postvar` and then the value of `postvar` is incremented.

Or with another approach using `awk`:

```
awk -v postvar=1 '{gsub($2,"&"postvar,$2);postvar++}1' inputfile
```

Here,`gsub` function is used to add the counter to the second column.

PS: You can use `OFS="\t"` to change the output format.

Comment: Just adding to this, you could negate the need to initialise and use postvar variable by using NR for the record number instead and so: awk '{ $2=$2NR }1'

Comment: Also you could just do `$2=$2 postvar++`, instead of assignment and then a separate increment.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl script, this is easy to solve. Let you try the below code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$^I=".bak";
$,="\t";
my $i=0;
while(<>)
{
     $i++;
     s/(bed2gff)/\1$i/;
     print;
}
```

Please get cleared before downvoting..

Comment: adding space to the end of your regex makes it rerunable, but wasn't a requirement.  I love perl.

Comment: Oh that's fine. I didn't notice it. Though I can help you I think.

Comment: I have a doubt, then it is needed to be replaced by spaces right?

Comment: s/(bed2gff\s)/\1$i/;

Answer (score 0):

Bash to the rescue. lol

```
[root@cal180 ~]# /bin/cp -f back.dat dat.txt ; bash test.sh dat.txt; cat dat.txt 
complete 6
chr22   bed2gff1 .   16850754    16850929     1000   .   .   .;
chr22   bed2gff2 .   17556275    17556923     864    .   .   .;
chr22   bed2gff3 .   17558078    17558342     642    .   .   .;
chr22   bed2gff4 .   17558390    17558813     941    .   .   .;
chr22   bed2gff5 .   17558918    17559181     698    .   .   .;
[root@cal180 ~]# cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
i=1;
lc=$(cat $1 | wc -l)
while reptext="bed2gff$i" && [ "$lc" -ge "$i" ] && sed -i "0,/bed2gff /s/bed2gff /$reptext /1" $1 && ((i++)); do :; done;
[root@cal180 ~]#
```